# Free FMX component in Android / iOS

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

There are a lot of discussion about how to free component in mobile device with Firemonkey, but that not response to my answer.

With 10.4 RAD Studio version, Embarcadero unified memory management.

I create a TFrame with :

```
FFrame := TMyFrame.Create(nil);
FFrame.OnClickCloseButton := CloseFrame;
```

On my CloseFrame method I do :

```
FFrame.DisposeOf;
FFrame := nil;
```

It's ok on Android, but on iOS I got a Access Violation. Normally with 10.4 version of the IDE, I can do :

```
FFrame.Free;
```

But I got application crash in iOS.

What I need to do is really the most simple stuff. Create something and free it.

What do you recommend ? Use interface with a IFrame for example ?

Comment: Instead of DisposeOf, try Release if it exists.

Comment: With Release, I get a "Adresse de l'objet exception : 0x0" and it's look like it's release the object but dont free the graphical space. When my frame is open at bottom, after Release I get a white rectangle.

Comment: Release should also work, if it does not, there is something else going on.

Comment: You can not free/destroy any component from any of its own events. This holds true for both VCL and FMX components. Why you can't do this? Usually your Event handler method is executed from components code like `if Assigned(FSomeEvent) then FSomeEvent`. So once execution of your event handler method finishes the code jumps back to the code that called your event method. Now since that code was called from a component instance that at this point no longer exists because you have just destroyed it your program will raise mentioned access violation.

Comment: As I use a procedure of object, the code isn't executed in the frame, or maybe I misunderstood ?

Comment: Yes it is. It is executed synchronously, so it starts from the frame and when that code is done, execution will continue at the calling place - in the frame like @SilverWarior explained. Some platforms are more forgiving to such scenarios than the others, so same code can appear to work on Windows and it can crash on other platforms.

Comment: @Bosshoss You are correct. The code inside your procedure of object is not executed in the the scope of your frame. The problem here is that your procedure of object is called/executed from within the procedure/code that belongs to the frame. And as it is always when you call one procedure from another once that one procedure finishes its execution the code always returns back to the procedure from when your other procedure was called. ...

Comment: .. Lets look at this simple example. You have two procedures `ProcedureA` and `ProcedureB`. So you do some work in `ProcedureA`, and then call your `ProcedureB` from your `ProcedureA`. Now you will be doing something in your `ProcedureB`. But once work in `ProcedureB` is done the code will always return back to` ProcedureA` to the next line after the `ProcedureB` was called from. Even if you call your `ProcedureB` from the last line of `ProcedureA` the code will always return back to `ProcedureA` once work is done in `ProcedureB`.

Comment: You can easily observe this by creating any two procedures, calling one from the other and stepping through your code using F7 to see how it progress. You could step through them using F8 in case if both of them contain breakpoints. With F7 it is possible to step into other procedures even if they don't have any breakpoints set in them.

Comment: NOTE this is the standard way of how code executes in Delphi or in any of teh Object Oriented Languages. All object Oriented Languages have this main procedure from where your application code starts and where it eventually always returns. Some languages clearly define this as`Main` procedure. Delphi doesn't bit it is still there. Where? Right there in your project file. You know that begin..end that encapsulates those `Application.Initialize`, `Application.CreateForm(TForm1: Form1)` and `Application.Run` calls that Delphi inserts into your project file by default.